# Postgres role without attribute Login

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I am a bit confused by the role attribute `LOGIN | NONLOGIN`, where [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createrole.html) says:

> These clauses determine whether a role is allowed to log in; that is,
>   whether the role can be given as the initial session authorization
>   name during client connection. A role having the LOGIN attribute can
>   be thought of as a user. Roles without this attribute are useful for
>   managing database privileges, but are not users in the usual sense of
>   the word. If not specified, NONLOGIN is the default, except when CREATE
>   ROLE is invoked through its alternative spelling CREATE USER.

What is a possible restriction with `NONLOGIN`? Why would people want a role with `NONLOGIN` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The clause is **`NOLOGIN`**, not <strike>`NONLOGIN`</strike>. (I suggest copy/paste for quotes.)

The clause is for "group" roles, which used to actually be `GROUP` before Postgres 8.1 - which is still supported. [See `CREATE GROUP` in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creategroup.html) Related:

- [Why did PostgreSQL merge users and groups into roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8485387/939860)

Group roles are very useful to bundle privileges and then grant / revoke the whole package to `LOGIN` roles. See:

- [Grant privileges for a particular database in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24923877/939860)

Or to act as demons within the database:

- [Allow insertion only from within a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20155754/939860)

Answer (score 0):

With NOLOGIN attribute role has no have permissions to connect to database. And vice versa with LOGIN.

In a simple way - USER is a ROLE with LOGIN attribute ('everything' here is a role in a Postgres).
Group role - is a role without LOGIN attribute (or with NOLOGIN attribute).

Therefore you can add role to a role to have more efficient permissions and grants management and decrease security threat.

For example I want to create a role with only read permissions, let's say *only_read_permission*

```
CREATE ROLE only_read_permission;
```

and I want have numerous users in database that can have access for reading each others tables.

Let's create a user (a role with LOGIN attribute) +*only_read_permission* role:

```
CREATE USER mikeaksenov IN ROLE only_read_permission;
```

And let's all my new created tables will have select permissions to all other users that have *only_read_permission* role:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE mikeaksenov
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES to only_read_permission;
```

It's just example, so next time I can create *update_permission* role and add it to required users. And here is the questions - why do I need give my group roles a LOGIN attribute?
1. It's no much security here
2. There is no point in it (in this particular situation)

Another situation if you see that user doing a bad stuff you can just provide him with NOLOGIN attribute and then have a conversation with him (or anything else)

Anyway, you can do whatever you want in Postgres, it's quite agile.

It's quite confusing in a first place, but then you may start to love how you can precisely manage a user access.